# running prolog on a server from php (or make it daemon)

Tags: php, server, prolog, daemon, swi-prolog

I'm learning Prolog, and I do want to find out how it may be used for real world web applications. Everything works perfect on a localhost, but I have some troubles making my creation live.

To start it on a server I followed this tutorial: http://www.j-paine.org/dobbs/prolog_from_php.html

With some changes to php, I make it live.
My php code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Calling SWI-Prolog from PHP (short)</title>
</head>
<body>
<? 
  $cmd = "swipl -f /path/to/myfile.pl -g test,halt -t 'halt(1)'";

  system( $cmd );
  echo "\n";

  $output = exec( $cmd );
  echo $output;
  echo "\n";
?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works good, here is the result: http://37.139.24.44/index.php

Now, I also have prolog code, which launches a server on my localhost, with the help of:

```
server(Port) :-
        http_server(http_dispatch, [port(Port)]).
```

Example code is:

```
:- module(upload, [ run/0]).
:- use_module(library(http/thread_httpd)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_dispatch)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_parameters)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_mime_plugin)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_client)).
:- use_module(library(http/html_write)).
:- use_module(library(lists)).

:- http_handler(root(.),    upload_form, []).
:- http_handler(root(upload),   upload,      []).

run :-
    http_server(http_dispatch, [port(8080)]).

upload_form(_Request) :-
    reply_html_page(
        title('Upload a file'),
        [ h1('Upload a file'),
          form([ method('POST'),
             action(location_by_id(upload)),
             enctype('multipart/form-data')
           ],
           table([],
             [ tr([td(input([type(file), name(file)]))]),
               tr([td(align(right),
                  input([type(submit), value('Upload!')]))])
             ]))
        ]).

upload(Request) :-
    (   memberchk(method(post), Request),
        http_read_data(Request, Parts, [form_data(mime)]),
        member(mime(Attributes, Data, []), Parts),
        memberchk(name(file), Attributes),
        memberchk(filename(Target), Attributes)
    ->  % process file here; this demo just prints the info gathered
        atom_length(Data, Len),
        format('Content-type: text/plain~n~n'),
        format('Need to store ~D characters into file \'~w\'~n',
           [ Len, Target ]),
        name(Data,Lis),
        write(Lis)
    ;   throw(http_reply(bad_request(bad_file_upload)))
    ).

:- multifile prolog:message//1.

prolog:message(bad_file_upload) -->
    [ 'A file upload must be submitted as multipart/form-data using', nl,
      'name=file and providing a file-name'
    ].
```

And I want to call this one from php, to constantly run it on a live server without any commands in terminal needed.

I've tried to change my php to

```
<? 
$cmd = "swipl -f /path/to/myfile.pl -g run,halt -t 'halt(1)'";
system( $cmd );
$output = exec( $cmd );
echo $output;
echo "\n";
?>
```

But it gives me just a blank screen.
I suppose that may be because I'm trying to run a server on already live server?

And if I try calling other predicate from php, it doesn't work with needed http libraries (or I just don't know how to call it correctly).

I'm not that good sysadmin, so I do need any advices how to run the script with a form on a server from php.

Or, if I can adapt it so that it works as a daemon on a server, using just SWIPL, that might also work for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Jocelyn has done a great job, it's a pity he doesn't follow (SWI)Prolog anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem in your case is that you invoke `halt/0` immediately after the server is spawned, so it does not have a chance to even listen to a single request.

In my experience, the best approach for web servers is to run SWI as a Unix **daemon**, which is what you also suggest. Please see the documentation of [**`library(http/http_unix_daemon)`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/http/http_unix_daemon.pl).

When you use this library, you can simply run the server as (for example):

```
$ swipl server.pl --user=www --pidfile=/var/run/http.pid
```

and it will continuously listen to requests and serve clients.

Note that if you use `library(http/http_unix_daemon)`, you do not even need auxiliary predicates like your `server/1`. All of that is handled implicitly.

During development, I recommend you use the `--interactive` command line flag when starting the server, so that you can interact with the server also on the toplevel.

Once it is finished, you can easily run the server on system startup.

Comment: @Olenka: `server.pl` is exactly the server code that you already have, with the following small differences: (1) add `:- use_module(library(http/http_unix_daemon)).` at the beginning, and (2) add `:- initialization http_daemon.` somewhere. This is enough to make the program process the command line parameters that are documented and simply start the server as a daemon.

Comment: I apparently deleted my previous comment. Thank you a lot for your answers, and for this explanations about server.pl, I really was missing what should be there.

Comment: Thanks again @mat , it worked for me. I just had to add --port option when I call swipl, as my server also uses apache.

Comment: Great! (This is only because you are just starting with Prolog: In my experience, with more exposure also comes the desire to do more and more with Prolog directly, and it then gradually replaces other tools.)

Comment: Thanks mat! Great answer, should be in SWI-Prolog FAQ.